# WinHttpSendRequest fails with ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE

Tags: c, winapi

Programmatically communicating with the web is not my area of expertise but I managed to make a read_web_page() function by cutting and pasting code from examples found online and the code has been working without error on a daily basis for many months.

It just so happened that my main windows-10 PC at work broke down and while waiting for it to be repaired and I am now forced to run the (the same) code from a windows-7 PC at home.

But now I have a error appear that I never saw before. I call the following code (simplified):

```
    // code to handle bad return values from the following three functions ommitted...

    HINTERNET hsession = WinHttpOpen(0,WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    HINTERNET hconnect = WinHttpConnect(hsession, (LPCWSTR)thewebsite, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT , 0);

    HINTERNET hrequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hconnect, L"GET", (LPCWSTR)thesubdirectory, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

    if (!WinHttpSendRequest(hrequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        int err = GetLastError();
```

Normally WinHttpSendRequest returns zero but now returns a non-zero value and GetLastError() returns a value of 12175 (equal to ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE).

The (https) URL I am connecting to has been the same all along and when I type it into my browser, the site still appears as normal.

Maybe the whole change of PC and location is a coincidence and the problem is caused by an under-the-hood change in the website I am reading (it is not under my control)... but I have no idea how to begin diagnosing (or fixing) the fault. Could it be something to do with my ISP?

The [documentation for WinHttpSendRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that more detailed information can be found for this error by setting up a callback function but the documentation describing how this is done is incomprehensible to me and I can not find any example code anywhere.

**EDIT:** To address Barmak's concerns about thewebsite and thesubdirectory, the code that creates them is here below:

```
char *char_thewebsite = "www.thewebsite.com";
char *char_thesubdirectory = "sub";

int n_website = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, char_thewebsite, -1, NULL, 0);
int n_subdir = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, char_thesubdirectory, -1, NULL, 0);

thewebsite = new WCHAR[n_website];
thesubdirectory = new WCHAR[n_subdir];

MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, char_thewebsite, -1, (LPWSTR)thewebsite, n_website);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, char_thesubdirectory, -1, (LPWSTR)thesubdirectory, n_subdir);
```

Comment: `(LPCWSTR)thewebsite` This cast is suspicious. What is the declaration for `thewebsite` and `thesubdirectory`? Is it `char` or `std::string` etc. ?

Comment: That error means the website doesn't support secure connection. Did the target website lose its secure connection? Try accessing the site with `INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT` and replace `WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE` with zero. By the way, WinINet is much easier if you just want to read a website.

Comment: @Barmack: if I do that then later when I call WinHttpReceiveResponse(hrequest, NULL) it returns a non-zero value and getlasterror is 12175 again.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong flags. How do you access the site through a web browser? `"http://www.thewebsite.com"` or `"https://www.thewebsite.com"`

Comment: the latter - the "https"

Comment: I tried your code on Win7, it works with `char thewebsite = "stackoverflow.com"` and `char_thesubdirectory = "questions";` using secure connect the way you have listed in the question.

Comment: @Barmak: I would expect the code to work... maybe this is pointing towards a coincidence of some subtle change in the website?... or a strange interaction with my ISP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long comment not an answer!

WinINet is much easier, you can use WinINet library if you don't need WinHTTP server capabilities. However you cannot use both WinINet and WinHTTP.

When declaring strings, it's best to start with UTF-16 strings `wchar_t *str = L"str"`. Sometimes your source string is in UTF-8, in that case you can use `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8...)` to convert to UTF-16.

WinINet example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinINet.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "WinINet.lib")

int main()
{
    const wchar_t* url = L"https://stackoverflow.com/questions";
    std::ofstream fout(L"c:\\test\\test.htm");
    HINTERNET hopen = InternetOpen(L"MyAppName",
        INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if(hopen)
    {
        DWORD flags = INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE;
        if(wcsstr(url, L"https://") == url)
            flags |= INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;
        HINTERNET hinternet = InternetOpenUrl(hopen, url, NULL, 0, flags, 0);
        if(hinternet)
        {
            char buf[1024];
            DWORD received = 0;
            while(InternetReadFile(hinternet, buf, sizeof(buf), &received))
            {
                if(!received) break;
                fout.write(buf, received);
            }
            std::cout << "success!\n";
            InternetCloseHandle(hinternet);
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(hopen);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had to make a few small tweaks to get it to compile - perhaps because my character set is set to "use multi-byte character set" ... but anyway, it is now working without errors. BTW I think you can use both WinINet and WinHTTP in the same program so long as you don't include Winhttp.h and WinINet.h in the same source file. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I forgot WinHTTP is Unicode only, that explains the conversions you were making. WinInet functions have ANSI version which can accept `char*` input.